# Incorrect selection of jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, html, css

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cvh2013/EWebt/3/) Fiddle, a jQuery dialog is displayed when you click on an image. The dialog should contain text specific to the image, for example, a text on law firms for the law firms image, a text on industry for the industry image, etc.

The problem is that once you've clicked each of the three images, any further click on any image returns the dialog that relates to the last of the three images you clicked, rather than the dialog for the image you've just clicked.

Can someone please point out what I've got wrong?

HTML

```
<div id="sf">

    <a href="dialogcontent/lawfirms.html" title="Law firms" id="sfimage">
        <div class="circle hovershadow lawfirms lawfirms-box-shadow">Law firms</div>
    </a> 
    <a href="dialogcontent/industry.html" title="Industry" id="sfimage">
        <div class="circle hovershadow industry industry-box-shadow">Industry</div>
    </a> 
    <a href="dialogcontent/in-house.html" title="In-house legal counsel" id="sfimage">
    <div class="circle hovershadow in-house in-house-box-shadow text">In-house
            legal counsel</div> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $loading = $('<img src="http://ubuntuone.com/5qQ3i4ctM8HAvRsSIZKgqd" alt="Loading ..." class="loading">'); 
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')

$('#sf a').each(function () {

         $dialog.append($loading.clone());
    var $link = $(this).one('click', function () {
        $dialog.load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
            .dialog({
            title: $link.attr('title'),
            width: 500,
            height: 300
        });

        $link.click(function (e) {

        //    e.preventDefault();
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
        });

        return false;
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 'one' method. So the click event is executed at most once per element.

So the last loaded content in dialog would be displayed, if the handler for that element already executed.

Comment: Thank you, what could I replace it with?

Comment: You can use bind() for that. But I am not sure what you have done is correct.